# Modify a pattern to allow "+" or "-" to appear at the front of the phrase

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a working pattern

```
/[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|/
```

that splits single words or phrases (in double or single quotes) separated by a space into an matches array. I want to modify the pattern to allow "+" sign or "-" sign to appear at the beginning of the word/phrase so preg_match_all dont splits the + or - into a separate match ie:

```
guide -"test * of" +'guide'
```

I want it to split into below matches

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => guide
        [1] => -"test * of"
        [2] => +'guide'
    )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following pattern:
`/[+-]?([^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')/`